# Appending pandas dataframes after looping through layers

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, append

I need some help with the final step of formatting API results for import to a PostgreSQL database. The structure of the data is:

```
[{  "season": 0,
    "seasonType": "string",
    "week": 0,
    "polls": [
      {
        "poll": "string",
        "ranks": [
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "school": "string",
            "conference": "string",
            "firstPlaceVotes": 0,
            "points": 0 }]}]}]
```

Here's the code I'm using to unpack it (of course if there is a better, more efficient way to do this too, all ears):

```
year = list(range(2020,2021))
req = []
pbp = pd.DataFrame()
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 1a2b3c4d"}
for year in tqdm(year, desc = 'fetch record'):
    parameters = {"year":year, "seasonType":"regular"}
    req = requests.get("https://api.collegefootballdata.com/rankings", headers=headers, params = parameters)
    r = req.json()
    print(type(r))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(r, columns = ['season', 'seasonType', 'week'], dtype = int)
    pbp = pbp.append(json.loads(req.text))
    for polls in pbp["polls"]:
        try:
            p1 = polls[1]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(p1)
        poll = df2["poll"]
        y = df1.append(poll)
        for rank in df2["ranks"]:
            df3 = pd.DataFrame(rank, index=[0])
            z = y.append(df3)
```

When I append, the data comes out like this:

| year | season | week | poll | rank | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | regular | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2020 | regular | 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | AP |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 1 | Alabama |
| 2020 | regular | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2020 | regular | 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | AP |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 2 | Clemson |

And, I'd like it to look like this:

| year | season | week | poll | rank | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | regular | 1 | AP | 1 | Alabama |
| 2020 | regular | 1 | AP | 2 | Clemson |
| 2020 | regular | 2 | AP | 1 | Alabama |
| 2020 | regular | 2 | AP | 2 | Clemson |

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which line of code is executed. It seems you have to write code in different way and first get all values in row and later append to dataframe. But you first append only `year  season  week`, next append only `poll`, and next you append only `rank` - and this makes all your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you use too many `append()`.

You should first create list/dictionary with all values in row, and finally append this row.

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

year = range(2020, 2021)
df = pd.DataFrame()

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXX"
}

for year in tqdm(year, desc='fetch record'):
    parameters = {
        "year": year,
        "seasonType": "regular"
    }

    url = "https://api.collegefootballdata.com/rankings"
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    
    #print(data[0])
    
    for item in data:
        row = {
            'year':   item['season'],
            'season': item['seasonType'],
            'week':   item['week'],
        }
    
        for poll in item["polls"]:
            row['poll'] = poll["poll"]
            for rank in poll["ranks"]:
                row['rank'] = rank["rank"]
                row['team'] = rank["school"]
                #print(row)
                df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
                
print(df)
```

Result:

```
       year   season  week                        poll  rank            team
0    2020.0  regular   1.0                   AP Top 25   1.0         Clemson
1    2020.0  regular   1.0                   AP Top 25   2.0      Ohio State
2    2020.0  regular   1.0                   AP Top 25   3.0         Alabama
3    2020.0  regular   1.0                   AP Top 25   4.0         Georgia
4    2020.0  regular   1.0                   AP Top 25   5.0        Oklahoma
..      ...      ...   ...                         ...   ...             ...
845  2020.0  regular  16.0  Playoff Committee Rankings  21.0  Oklahoma State
846  2020.0  regular  16.0  Playoff Committee Rankings  22.0        NC State
847  2020.0  regular  16.0  Playoff Committee Rankings  23.0           Tulsa
848  2020.0  regular  16.0  Playoff Committee Rankings  24.0  San José State
849  2020.0  regular  16.0  Playoff Committee Rankings  25.0        Colorado

[850 rows x 9 columns]
```

---

**EDIT**

The same using special functions like `.read_json()`, `.explode()` `.apply(pd.Series)`

```
# ... code ...

response = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers)

df = pd.read_json(response.text)

df = df.explode(['polls'])
df['poll'] = df['polls'].str['poll']
df['ranks'] = df['polls'].str['ranks']
df = df.explode(['ranks'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df['ranks'].apply(pd.Series))
df.drop(columns=['polls', 'ranks'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
     season seasonType  week  ...         conference  firstPlaceVotes  points
0      2020    regular     1  ...                ACC             38.0  1520.0
1      2020    regular     1  ...            Big Ten             21.0  1504.0
2      2020    regular     1  ...                SEC              2.0  1422.0
3      2020    regular     1  ...                SEC              0.0  1270.0
4      2020    regular     1  ...             Big 12              0.0  1269.0
..      ...        ...   ...  ...                ...              ...     ...
845    2020    regular    16  ...             Big 12              NaN     NaN
846    2020    regular    16  ...                ACC              NaN     NaN
847    2020    regular    16  ...  American Athletic              NaN     NaN
848    2020    regular    16  ...      Mountain West              NaN     NaN
849    2020    regular    16  ...             Pac-12              NaN     NaN

[850 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: this was super helpful, and worked great. I was playing around with this dataset while concurrently doing something similar for work and this solution got me over the hump at work too! Thank you!